# How one can show that $\int _0 ^1 ((h')^2-h^2)dx \ge0 $ for all $h\in C^1[0,1]$ and $h(0) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How one can show that $\int _0 ^1 ((h')^2-h^2)dx \ge0 $ for all $h\in C^1[0,1]$ and $h(0) = 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of Calculus:
$$
\left|h(x)\right| = \left|\int_0^x h'(t) \,dt\right| \le \int_0^x \left|h'(t)\right| \,dt \le \int_0^1 \left|h'(x)\right| \,dx
$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz (or Jensen's) inequality:

$$
\left|h(x)\right|^2 \le \left(\int_0^1 \left|h'(x)\right| \,dx\right)^2 \le \int_0^1 \left|h'(x)\right|^2 \,dx
$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$ to get:

$$
\int_0^1 \left|h(x)\right|^2\,dx \le \int_0^1 \left|h'(x)\right|^2 \,dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

One can't, because it is false. Consider $h(x) = 1$, $h'(x) = 0$, $\int_0^1 ((h'(x))^2 - (h(x))^2) d x = -1$.

Comment: I edited, your example now doesn't work

Comment: The condition $h(0) = 0$ was there when I added my answer.

Comment: @AymanHourieh It seems to me that you dont use that condition and I deleted it, but after vorbrand's answer I understood it and again added.

Comment: Got me worried ;-)

Comment: @Ashot As you've figured out, the condition is used in the very first step. The fundamental theorem of Calculus says $h(x) - h(0) = \int_0^x h'(t) \,dt$.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is a (weak) version of a celebrated result---Wirtinger's inequality.